# How to rotate the legend labels to match the orientation in the plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The legend labels are vertically oriented, but after the call to `coord_flip()` I would expect them to be horizontally oriented.

How can I fix this?

```r
library(ggplot2)  
  
tbl <- structure(
  list(
    ppm_id = c(
      "PPM000001",
      "PPM000002",
      "PPM000014",
      "PPM000015",
      "PPM000050",
      "PPM000051",
      "PPM000084",
      "PPM000085"
    ),
    estimate_type_long = c(
      "Odds Ratio",
      "Odds Ratio",
      "Hazard Ratio",
      "Hazard Ratio",
      "Hazard Ratio",
      "Hazard Ratio",
      "Hazard Ratio",
      "Relative Risk "
    ),
    estimate = c(1.55, 1.63, 1.21, 1.14, 1.17,
                 1.24, 1.17, 1.2),
    interval_lower = c(1.52, 1.6, 1.17, 1.02, 1.13,
                       1.15, 1.01, 1.05),
    interval_upper = c(1.58, 1.67, 1.26, 1.28,
                       1.21, 1.34, 1.34, 1.38)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -8L),
  class = c("tbl_df",
            "tbl", "data.frame")
)

ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(
         x = ppm_id,
         y = estimate,
         ymin = interval_lower,
         ymax = interval_upper,
         col = estimate_type_long
       )) +
  geom_pointrange() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, lty = 2) +  # add a dotted line at x=1 after flip
  coord_flip() +  # flip coordinates (puts labels on y axis)
  xlab("Label") + ylab("Mean (95% CI)") +
  theme_bw()  # use a white background
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: If I'm reading things correctly, it looks like the key glyph for a "pointrange" layer is currently always vertical (I looked at the glyph examples [here](https://www.hvitfeldt.me/blog/changing-glyph-in-ggplot2/#showcase)). How about switching to using a points layer plus an error bar layer with width = 0? Looks like error bars show horizontal lines in the glyph. (Aside, in current versions of ggplot2 you can build your plot "horizontally" instead of needing `coord_flip()` by switching x and y variables and using xmin/xmax :) )

Comment: Hmm, it looks like **ggstance** switched orientation of legend keys when making horizontal layers; see later comments in this issues thread: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1389. Maybe a horizontal version of `draw_key_pointrange` is needed?

Comment: Indeed I can use as an alternative a error bar layer. Would you mind posting an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to use point and error bar layers instead of `geom_pointrange()`. Error bars have horizontal line key glyphs where pointrange has vertical lines in the keys.

Use `width = 0` in `geom_errorbar()` to get rid of the end bars. You'll need to fiddle with the point size here to make them "fatter" (the pointrange layer has a `fatten` argument for this); I thought `size = 2` looked close.

```
ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(
           x = ppm_id,
           y = estimate,
           ymin = interval_lower,
           ymax = interval_upper,
           col = estimate_type_long
       )) +
    geom_point(size = 2) +
    geom_errorbar(width = 0) +
    # geom_pointrange() +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 1, lty = 2) +  # add a dotted line at x=1 after flip
    coord_flip() +  # flip coordinates (puts labels on y axis)
    xlab("Label") + ylab("Mean (95% CI)") +
    theme_bw()  # use a white background
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>